# What makes facebook pages load so fast

Tags: mysql, performance

I am also a php programmer. I always wondered how do Facebook pages load so fast with so many users connecting to them at any instance. My site never reached such speed even when the traffic was less. What do they do so very well for their sites?

What should i take care of even if i want to make a website even half the speed of Facebook. I am referring to php and mysql and jquery websites.

Comment: What kind of machine hosts your page? what kind of internet connection does that machine have? My guess is that Facebook's equipment regarding that is top notch, to begin with. In addition they use hiphop, which transforms php to c++...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at this reddit post by someone who interned at Facebook:

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/nav19/facebook_releases_hhvm_60_percent_faster_than_its/c37pitt

Most relevant parts of the post:

> - Database calls have cache keys. Memcached short-circuits the database hits. Facebook has a > 99.9% hit rate. Occasionally, there can be an issue which causes the hit rate to decrease to 95%. This probably doesn't happen much, but when it did, it made the whole site unusably slow.
> - Stupid database calls that fetch a lot are generally better than smart database calls that fetch minimally. Why? Because most of the stupid database calls are the same - and therefore very cacheable - and using server resources to filter stuff out is therefore much more economical than using database resources. Or, in other words, it lessens the complexity of the database calls and makes fewer at the expense of more data per database call, and more of the load shifted to memcached.

Answer (score 4):

Facebook has very highly tuned caching and a highly tweaked MySQL cluster setup. Try searching 'MySQL at Facebook' within Facebook. Some of their hints and tips are legendary!

Without knowing what your site is, how its coded, the database structure etc it would be impossible to say how to optimise your site.

Working with big databases day in day out even the most insignificant change to a query can have massive implications to performance. Don't just slap an index across a whole table, use a decent index engine such as Sphinx not just the internal MySQL index. Optimise all your database calls to within a nats hair of their lives.

Also configure MySQL logging for slow_queries etc.

O'Reilly do a couple of good ebooks on performance MySQL.

Dave

Answer (score 2):

They basically:

- Scale horizontally
- Compile their PHP code
- Use MySQL in a highly distributed fashion as if it was a NoSQL database (this means they don't join that much when querying it)
- Cache a lot

Comment: I did not get the concept of "don't join" . You mean to say data are saved in a single table ?

Comment: Sort of. That's what NO_SQL basically do. They store data in huge hashes. And they avoid joining relations to improve query performance.